# Convert JSON Object array into associative array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Assuming I have 2 JSON Object arrays, which looks like this:

**Resources:**

```
[{
    "DefinitionId": 193041,
    "ResourceId": -2147290607,
    "AssetId": 193041
}, {
    "DefinitionId": 193042,
    "ResourceId": -2147290603,
    "AssetId": 193042
}]
```

**ResourceIds**

```
[193041, 193041, 193041, 193042]
```

**The use-case:**

I need to list the details from my Resources JSONObject for each ResourceId. For example I want to output the `AssetId` for every `ResourceId` in `ResourceIds`.

**My plan:**

I thought it would be an elegant solution to convert my `Resources` JSON into an associative array, so that I could access the `AssetId` for my `ResourceId` '193041' like this: `Resources[193041].AssetId` . The problem: I could only think about long code to convert my above `Resources` JSON into an associative JSON object.

**The question:**

How can I convert the above Resources JSON object array into an associative object array with ResourceId as key?

**Desired Resources.json:**

```
{
    "-2147290607": {
        "DefinitionId": 193041,
        "ResourceId": -2147290607,
        "AssetId": 193041
    },
    "-2147290603": {
        "DefinitionId": 193042,
        "ResourceId": -2147290603,
        "AssetId": 193042
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show desired result?

Comment: @NenadVracar sure, edited!

Comment: btw, [JSON](http://json.org/) is a serialized object in string form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object and iterate the array with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

and assign the element to the property with the name of `a.ResourceId`.

The callback uses an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), because there is only one assignment.

```js
var data = [{ "DefinitionId": 193041, "ResourceId": -2147290607, "AssetId": 193041 }, { "DefinitionId": 193042, "ResourceId": -2147290603, "AssetId": 193042 }],
    object = {};

data.forEach(a => object[a.ResourceId] = a);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you mind to elloborate this a bit: `data.forEach(a => object[a.ResourceId] = a);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var resources = [{
    "DefinitionId": 193041,
    "ResourceId": -2147290607,
    "AssetId": 193041
}, {
    "DefinitionId": 193042,
    "ResourceId": -2147290603,
    "AssetId": 193042
}];

var resourceIds =[193041, 193041, 193041, 193042];

var res = resources.reduce( function(prev, curr) {
  // Check AssetId
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf
  if ( resourceIds.indexOf( curr.AssetId ) >= 0 ) prev[ curr.ResourceId ] = curr;
  return prev;
}, {} );

var resJSON = JSON.stringify( res );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Resources = [{
    "DefinitionId": 193041,
    "ResourceId": -2147290607,
    "AssetId": 193041
}, {
    "DefinitionId": 193042,
    "ResourceId": -2147290603,
    "AssetId": 193042
}];     

Resources.find(function(value){return value.ResourceId === -2147290603}).AssetId
```

or use lodash/underscore for an elegant solution:
    _.find(Resources, {ResourceId : -2147290603}).AssetId;

With this we can find the required AssetId by just passing the ResourceId. We can even skip the conversion of JSON for simplicity.